# Accidental Oblivion

Tags: lateral-thinking

She was running track, as usual. He approached to stop her, but accidentally stumbled. As a result, no one remembered the next couple of minutes.

What happened?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

She is a

> CD or record or a music player of some sort.

He approached to stop her, but accidentally stumbled. As a result, no one remembered the next couple of minutes.

> The owner of this cd meant to pause the track but instead pressed next, which forwarded to the next track, which is why no one remembers the rest of the track.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is :

> "She" is a camera, running on a track (often called a dolly, I believe). The operator approached to stop the camera's motion, but stumbled and caused the camera to either stop filming or to film something other than the intended subject, losing the record of the event for the next few minutes.

Comment: Nice answer, but that's not what happened.